# Hibernate JPA Caching

Tags: hibernate, jpa, caching

I have a table named **Master_Info_tbl**. Its a lookup table:

Here is the code for the table:

```
 @Entity
@Table(name="MASTER_INFO_T")
 public class CodeValue  implements java.io.Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = -3732397626260983394L;
 private Integer objectid;
 private String codetype;
 private String code;
 private String shortdesc;
 private String longdesc;
 private Integer dptid;
 private Integer sequen;
 private Timestamp begindate;
 private Timestamp enddate;
 private String username;
 private Timestamp rowlastchange;
 //getter Setter methods
```

I have a service layer which calls the method 
       
**service.findbycodeType("Code1");**
   same way this table is queried for the other code types as well **e.g. code2, code3 and so on till code10**  which gets the result set from the same table and is shown into the drop down of the jsp pages since these drop downs are in 90% of the pages I am thinking to cache them globally. 
**Any idea how to achieve this?

 FYI: I am using JPA and Hibernate with Struts2 and Spring. The database being used is DB2 UDB8.2**

---

**@Pascal**
Thank you very much for all your responses. It has helped me a lot.I implemented everything what I supposed to implement(I Think). Still I dont know if the second level caching is working or not.Since I am not able to see anything in the logging in the log4j logging file from cache and also nothing is showing up in the console. In order to show that second level cache implementation is working I need to have some kind of proof and need to show it to my manager.So I am kind of stuck. 
**Please help!**
 I know I am very close to finish it up but just.... 
**Here is my code(if you think something is missing or something should not be there please do let me know):
Entity Class**

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Table(name = "CODEVALUE_T")
public class CodeValue implements java.io.Serializable {
//all the field name with getter and setter
}
```

**Persistence.xml:**

```
<properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider" />
        </properties>
```

**Service Layer DAO:**

```
try {
            System.out.println("Calling the findByCodetype() method");
            final String queryString = "select model from CodeValue model where model.codetype"
                    + "= :propertyValue" + " order by model.code";

            Query query = em.createQuery(queryString);
            query.setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true);
            query.setParameter("propertyValue", propertyName);
            return query.getResultList();

        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            logger.error("findByCodetype failed: ", re);
            throw re;
        }
```

**Log4j.property value to show the verbose**
log4j.category.org.hibernate.cache=DEBUG
**ehcache.xml code(It's location is in src/ folder same place where my struts.xml file is located)**

```
<ehcache>
   <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
   <defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="6000"
        timeToLiveSeconds="12000"
        overflowToDisk="true"
        diskPersistent="false"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
        />

</ehcache>
```

Answer (score 13):

> (...) since these drop downs are in 90% of the pages I am thinking to cache them globally.

Using the [query cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-querycache) would be very appropriate for this use case. So activate the [second-level cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache), cache the `CodeValue` entity (see [2.2.8. Caching entities](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2298)) and put the query behind `findbycodeType` in the [query cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-querycache). To do so, use:

```
javax.persistence.Query query = manager.createQuery(...);
query.setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true);
```

And to clarify, *the combination of the query and the values provided as parameters to that query is used as a key, and the value is the list of identifiers for that query*. 
Schematically, something like that:

```
*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*
|                              Query Cache                                 |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| [ "from CodeValue c where c.codetype=?", ["Code1"] ] -> [ 1, 2, ... ]    |
| [ "from CodeValue c where c.codetype=?", ["Code2"] ] -> [ 3, 5, 6, ... ] |
*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*
```

So calling your method with different arguments won't "flush previous data", the argument is part of the key (or the query cache wouldn't work).

Note that this is Hibernate specific, JPA 1.0 doesn't specify second-level cache and query caching.

#### See also

- [Hibernate: Truly Understanding the Second-Level and Query Caches](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html)

Comment: As I mentioned I am using jpa with hibernate and for some reason when I try to set em.setCacheable(true); i am not able to do it.
This is the entitymanger code:

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

@PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }
Is there any jar file I am missing?

Comment: I got another solution as follows: if (query instanceof org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl) { logger .info("Yes the query is of the instance org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl so alreaedy set the cacheable true"); ((org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl) query).getHibernateQuery() .setCacheable(true); } do u think it might work...

Comment: @Pascal Thankyou very much for the update. I have implemented the 2nd level cache. now How do I know that the caching is working properly. I meant to say I just want to make sure that the object which I am marking as cacheable are there in the cache somewhere?

Comment: @Sameer Configure Hibernate to *Log all second-level cache activity*. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293866/knowing-when-hitting-database-vs-cache/2293885#2293885)

Comment: @Pascal Please look into the new Answer I have posted and if you have any suggestion on it.

Answer (score 6):

> Hibernate sadly logs the sql statements to the console even if the hit comes from the cache.

Wrong, Hibernate doesn't log sql statements if the cache has been used, confirmed with the following config:

persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
```

Entity class:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "byNameLike", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE name like ?1",
  hints = { @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true") })
```

Logging:

```
Enabled org.hibernate.SQL category.
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [hibernate query cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-querycache) feature.

You can also use some lightweight standalone caching solution, like [OSCache](http://www.opensymphony.com/oscache/). It gives you full control over what, when, and how is cached, but you will need to also think when to refresh the cache.

Comment: I checked the link which you have provided but its not going to help me because I am using the same method and again next time I am calling the same method with different arguments(code1, code2, code3 etc.) so the previous data will be flushed automatically since its the same query only with different parameters.

Comment: I got another solution as follows:
if (query instanceof org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl) {
    logger
      .info("Yes the query is of the instance org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl so alreaedy set the cacheable true");
    ((org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl) query).getHibernateQuery()
      .setCacheable(true);
   }

do u think it might work...

Answer (score -2):

You don't see anything in the log because Cache doesn't inform you abozt hits/misses per default. Use `statistics="true"` on your `defaultCache` element to include information about this.

Hibernate sadly logs the sql statements to the console even if the hit comes from the cache.

Comment: "Hibernate sadly logs the sql statements to the console even if the hit comes from the cache." Not true.